# cannot convert from from system.collections.generic.ienumerable<int> to object[]

Tags: linq

```
var qResult  = Enumerable.Range(1,10);
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(qResult);
```

The problem here occurs that "Argument'1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'object[]'

I have tried various codes to sort this out but failed. If anyone can help me please.

Answer (score 2):

AddRange doesnt take an enumerable. Give it an array if objects instead :)

```
        var qResult  = Enumerable.Range(1,10);
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(qResult.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I have tried var qResult  = Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray(); var qResult = Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray<object[]>(); and also comboBox1.Items.AddRange(qResult.ToArray()); But nothing seems to be happening.

Comment: Updated my answer for you. If you cast to object before ToArray you should get an object[] that he cant complain about :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to send an array of objects as the parameter:

```
var qResult  = Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(qResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

AddRange expects a list or array to bind to.  Call ToArray() on your enumerable as below:

```
var qResult  = Enumerable.Range(1,10);
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(qResult.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.Range` returns an `Enumerable` of integers , However, `AddRange` takes an array, so you should convert `qResult` to array, simply call `ToArray` method

```
qResult.ToArray()
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I have tried var qResult  = Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray(); var qResult = Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray<object[]>(); and also comboBox1.Items.AddRange(qResult.ToArray()); But nothing seems to be happening.